# Special values of the classical normalized Eisenstein series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, modular-forms

I am looking for a comprehensive list of some known special values of the classical normalized Eisenstein series $E_4(\tau)$ and $E_6(\tau)$. Does anyone know where I can find a table of some known explicit values of $E_4(\tau)$ and $E_6(\tau)$?

Comment: Sorry, what do you exactly mean by "special values"?

Comment: @user167762 In this context, *special* means expressible in closed form.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/340154/determination-of-special-values-of-eisenstein-series