# What are some specific values of Eisenstein Series?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Just as the person who made [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976426/special-values-of-the-classical-normalized-eisenstein-series), I am looking for specific values of Eisenstein series on certain values. Specifically, it would be nice to have the values of $E_k(\tau)$ for $k = 2,4$ and $\tau = i,2i$ or even generally $ni$ if possible! The references that I have found refer to only $E_{4k}$ and Hurwitz numbers, both of which don't really help for my goals.

I'm looking for these values because I need to determine how to express certain weight 2 and 4 modular forms, $q_2 \in \mathcal{M}_2(\Gamma_0(2))$ and $q_4 \in \mathcal{M}_4(\Gamma_0(2))$, on $\Gamma_0(2)$ in terms of Eisenstein bases or, even better, q-expansions. My group and I suspect that $q_2 = \lambda G_{2,2}$ for some lambda, but we're having trouble figuring out the specifics. Knowing certain values, or even general relations would be integral for our project going forward.

Comment: All these Eisenstein series can be evaluated in terms of singular moduli and elliptic integrals corresponding to these singular moduli. More generally they can be evaluated for $\tau=i\sqrt{n} $ where $n$ is a positive rational number in terms of values of Gamma function at rational points and certain algebraic numbers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That sounds perfect for our goals, do you happen to have a source that describes the methods for how to perform these evaluations?

Comment: You will need to study theta functions, elliptic integrals and related topics to see the connection. I have described the theory in some of my blog posts. Will post some relevant links after some time.

Comment: You may have a look at [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/05/certain-lambert-series-identities-and-their-proof-via-trigonometry-part-1.html?m=0) and the [next one](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/05/certain-lambert-series-identities-and-their-proof-via-trigonometry-part-2.html?m=0) to get the connection between Eisenstein series and elliptic integrals.

Comment: Also see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/988233/72031) about Chowla Selberg formula which relates the values of eta function to Gamma function.

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391229/72031).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh These are perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

- $E_4(i)$ is found by looking at $\int_0^1 dz=\int_0^1\frac{d\wp_i(z)}{\wp_i'(z)}=\int_C \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4x^3-g_2(i)x}}$ on the complex torus $\Bbb{C/(Z+iZ)} \cong E:y^2=4x^3-g_2(i)x$, it will reduce to $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}$ having a closed in term of $\Gamma(1/4)$ from the beta function $B(1/4,1/2)$.
- $E_4(ni)$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}[E_4(i),E_6(i)]=\Bbb{Q}[E_4(i)]$, this is because $E_4(nz)$ is a level $n$ modular form so the coefficients of $\prod_{ad=n,b\bmod d} (T-d^{-2}E_4(n\frac{az+b}{d}))$ are $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ modular forms with rational coefficients, they are in $\Bbb{Q}[E_4(z),E_6(z)]$. The coefficients of the polynomial $\prod_{ad=n,b\bmod d} (T-d^{-2}E_4(n\frac{ai+b}{d}))\in \Bbb{Q}[E_4(i)][T]$ are found from the first few Fourier coefficients.
- $E_2(i)$ is found from $z^{-2}G_2(-1/z)= G_2(z) - \frac{2\pi i}{z}$
- $E_2(i)-n E_2(ni)$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}[E_4(i)]$ because $E_2(z)-n E_2(nz)$ is a level $n$ modular form and the same reason as above.

The polynomials involved in the algebraic parts are **solvable**: this is due to that $i$ is a CM point, the roots of the polynomial $\prod_{ad=n,b\bmod d} (T-d^{-2}E_4(n\frac{ai+b}{d}))$ are grouped by ideal classes of $\Bbb{Z}[ni]$ giving an abelian Galois group (over $\Bbb{Q}[i,E_4(i)]$)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Do you know of any sources that cover these facts in detail?

Comment: Also, how could I go about figuring the expressions for $E_4(ni)$ and $E_2(i) - nE_2(ni)$ over $E_4(i)$?

Comment: I second the question about sources that cover these facts in detail.